# Check Box DataBinding / MinWidth Problems

Tags: xaml, listview, checkbox, data-binding, uwp

I am creating a UWP application and I want a simple check box, no text, for each entry in my ListView.  If I add a checkbox control to my template for the listview, I get a big gap after the checkbox for the Content - event when the content is empty.

If I turn on multiselect in the listview so I get a nice checkbox for each row, I can't seem to figure out how to databind the check box for each row in the listview to the Selected property of my ViewModel.

Below is a picture of what I want the area of the check box to look like.  This was generated using the  SelectionMode="Multiple" on the listview.  Remember - the problem with this approach is I can't seem to find a way to bind the check box to the Selected property of my ViewModel class.
[image: Image of using SelectionMode on ListView]

Below is what it looks like if I remove the SeletionMode property and add a check box to my ItemTemplate.  As you can see there is a huge gap between the check box and the area where the image will be due to the Checkbox control's minimum width of 120.

[image: Image using ItemTemplate]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set the `MinWidth` on the `Checkbox` itself

eg

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheck" IsChecked="True" MinWidth="30"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The alternative is creating a copy of the Checkbox Styles and Template but that seems like overkill here.

Comment: Worked great.. Thanks